# Parse a large string between single quotes with escaping

Tags: java, regex

I need to parse a string between single quotes with java.regex. The string may contain an escaped single quote in oracle style (to escape a `'` just put `''`).

For example: for `qwerty 'uiop asdfg''hjklzxcvb'` it must return `'uiop asdfg''hjklzxcvb'`

I have a code that works fine for a small string but if I try to parse quite a large string, I'll get `java.lang.StackOverflowError`. How can I rewrite my pattern so that it works fine with a large string?

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class RegexTest {
    static String STRING_BETWEEN_QUOTES_PATTERN = "'(?:[^']|'')*'";
    static String queryString = "qwerty 'uiop asdfg''hjklzxcvb' ";

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Pattern patternBetweenQuotes = Pattern.compile(STRING_BETWEEN_QUOTES_PATTERN);
        Matcher matcherBetweenQuotes = patternBetweenQuotes.matcher(queryString);

        while (matcherBetweenQuotes.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcherBetweenQuotes.group());
        }
    }
}
```

This code does not work for a such string:

> static String queryString = "qwerty 'uiop'' asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwerty qwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwertyqwerty uiop asdfghjklzxcvb nmqw ertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvb nmqwertyuiopasd fghjklzxcvbnm qwerty' ";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "unwrap" it:

```
"'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eG6vM8/3)

The reason your regex fails with longer strings is that the alternation requires lots of backtracking steps, and the solution is to make the regex more "linear".

Here is the regex breakdown:

- `'` - an apostrophe
- `[^']*` - 0  or more characters other than `'`
- `(?:''[^']*)*` - 0 or more groups of...

  - `''` - two literal `'`
  - `[^']*` - 0 or more characters other than `'`
- `'` - literal `'`

With my regex, your sample input is matched within 11 steps, and [`'(?:''|[^'])*'`](https://regex101.com/r/dH2mV7/1) finishes after 6271 steps.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest using this much faster regex:

```
final static String STRING_BETWEEN_QUOTES_PATTERN = "'(?:[^']+|'')*'";
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wG2rZ3/1)

Check the demo link where it **completes match in just 15 steps**. Whereas `'(?:[^']|'')*'` [takes whopping 4185 steps](https://regex101.com/r/jB0qX4/1).

Comment: There is hardly any appreciable difference between 15 & 11 (there might be none in Java since this demo is PCRE). I was actually comparing with OP's regex where difference is huge.

Comment: I just referred to your "much faster" :) Certainly, the difference is tiny.

Comment: Thank you very much! Both your answers work fine for me!